# Wireshark merging pcap files

Tags: wireshark, merge, timestamp

I'm trying to merge 15 pcap files using wireshark. The merging is successful.

I'm using the appending function so that the second file is just added to the bottom of the first file. But when this is done, I get a negative value in Time column. How can I change this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [joincap](https://github.com/assafmo/joincap).

```
go get -u github.com/assafmo/joincap
```

To merge `1.pcap` and `2.pcap`:

```
joincap 1.pcap 2.pcap > merged.pcap
```

I wrote `joincap` to overcome what I believe is bad error handling by `mergecap` and `tcpslice`.
For more details go to https://github.com/assafmo/joincap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the time difference between frame 4873 and 4874 is because these packets were from different files.

I would suggest using mergecap to merge the two PCAP files together instead of just concatenating (appending) them like you did. Mergecap merges the packets according to timestamp by default (using the "-a" switch in mergecap would result in a concatenated file like yours).

Another option is to load the two capture files into [CapLoader](http://caploader.com), select all flows, and export them to a new PCAP file (by using drag-and-drop from the PCAP icon).

Finally, if you really want to concatenate/append and NOT have the packets in chronological order, then you just have to right click the packet with the smallest timestamp (for example frame 4874) and select "Set Time Reference". That way all timestamps will be shown as relative to that packet in Wireshark.